# Add Facebook Pixel specific page in VUE SPA

Tags: vue.js, facebook-pixel

I have issue for adding specific facebook pixel for SPA Aplication in vue

```
<script>
  !(function(f, b, e, v, n, t, s) {
    if (f.fbq) return;
    n = f.fbq = function() {
      n.callMethod
        ? n.callMethod.apply(n, arguments)
        : n.queue.push(arguments);
    };
    if (!f._fbq) f._fbq = n;
    n.push = n;
    n.loaded = !0;
    n.version = '2.0';
    n.queue = [];
    t = b.createElement(e);
    t.async = !0;
    t.src = v;
    s = b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(t, s);
  })(
    window,
    document,
    'script',
    'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js'
  );
  fbq('init', 'test');
  fbq('track', 'PageView');
  fbq('track', 'CompleteRegistration');
</script>
<noscript>
  <img
    height="1"
    width="1"
    src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=1234456789&ev=PageView
  &noscript=1"
  />
</noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

i want to add this to my page domainname/register

how to add script head and no script head for specific page in Single Page Application VUE

Comment: Have you tried my solution? Is it working for you?

Comment: Its working thanks but pageview get multiple when i inspect using extension its ok ?

Comment: Page view when ever you refresh the app or call your site it loads. Its not an issue. If my answer helps you accept the answer and give a thumbs up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Step 1:*** Add `facebook pixel code` in your `public/index.html` inside `<head>` tag

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
  !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
  {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
  n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
  if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
  n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
  t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
  'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
  fbq('init', '266xxxxxxxx1');
  fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=266xxxxxxxx1&ev=PageView&noscript=1"/>
</noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

***Step 2:*** Inside your component `computed, methods, created` you can do,

Inside `methods` you can do,

```
methods: {
  addtoCart() {
    window.fbq('track', 'Add to your shopping cart')
  }
}
```

Inside `computed` you can do like

```
computed: {
  formattedRating () {
    window.fbq('track', 'Format your rating')
    return this.fixedPoints === null
      ? this.currentRating
      : this.currentRating.toFixed(this.fixedPoints)
  },
}
```

Inside `created` you can do like,

```
created() {
  this.loadPressRelease()
  window.fbq('track', 'Load press release')
},
```

[image]

You can call the `facebook pixel` event `faq` function using `window.faq` in any components

Comment: thanks! for anyone wondering, you can easily add a JSON object as parameter:
`fbq('track', 'Purchase', {currency: "USD", value: 30.00});`

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/meta-pixel/implementation/conversion-tracking/

Answer (score 0):

You can render this script based on the current route name.

First this has to be inside the mounted Vue app (Within `<router-view/>`) ex: inside a layout component if you have it.

Important, adding the script directly inside the Vue app could cause problems.
Therefore, better to move your script to a js file in your assets folder ex:
`/js/fbq.js`.

After that check the current route to render it like this:

```
<!-- Render based on route -->
<component v-if="$route.name == 'register'" :is="`script`" src="/js/fbq.js" async></component>
```

Comment: In fbs.js is include no script code ?